# How can I grant all privileges to root@localhost in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I'm using WAMP and I accidentally disable the `DELETE` privilege from `phpMyAdmin` GUI.

[image]

I have tried many ways like `mysql_upgrade` and change password. However, I still get the `error #1045: Access denied for user root@localhost` when I am trying to add the `DELETE` privilege.

How can I grant the full privileges back to root@localhost?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

1. Add `skip-grant-tables` in my.cnf file under the [mysqld] section or otherwise stop mysqld and start it with the --skip-grant-tables option.
2. Use `mysql` to connect to DB without password without -p
3. Then execute this:

   `UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
4. Then execute:
   `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';`

Answer (score 0):

Edit your my.ini configuration file usually located at `Drive:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql-x.x\my.ini`

Add this line in the `[mysql]` section:

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
```

Restart your MySQL server and restore the user permissions, after that remove that line and restart MySQL.

Comment: Then I get the `error #1290 - The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement`